# Apache velocity Round or Ceil without MathTools

Tags: math, velocity

using Apache velocity inside a third party application. Can not use MathTools. I want to round up or ceil the value of x/8

```
1/8 = 1
8/8 = 1
9/8 = 2
16/8 = 2
19/8 = 3
```

etc

What I am able to use inside velocity are Modulo `%` and basic `* / + -` Most answers online have casting which I can not use either

Comment: Don't cast it on velocity but you can create a utility class and pass to the template to perform the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really specific to Velocity, that's integer arithmetic. Anyway, you can emulate Ceil by adding 7 before dividing, and Round by taking the floor or the ceiling depending on the remaining.

```
#set($ceil = ($n + 7) / 8)

#set($round = $n / 8)
#if($n % 8 > 4) #set($round = $round + 1) #end
```